# drawing a cut in a circle in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I want to draw the following diagram involving a cut in a circle. I don't know how to do it. I want to draw the following diagram.
[image]

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[black,fill=yellow](0,0) circle (2.0);
    \end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

My output
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just add a white rectangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage [edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[black,fill=yellow](0,0) circle (2.0);
\draw [draw=white,fill=white] (0.8,2) rectangle (1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If the picture background is white, the following suggestion works:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=yellow](0,0) circle[radius=2];
\clip (1,-2) rectangle (1.3,2);
\fill[white] (0,-2) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or solution independent from background color: by use of two `arc`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=yellow] (60:2)  arc [start angle=60, end angle=300, radius=2];
\draw[fill=yellow] (310:2) arc [start angle=-50, end angle=50, radius=2];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]